# For $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ define the function $f_a:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ by the formula $f_a(x)=ax$. Show that $f_a(x)\in G$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $G=\{f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\,:\, \text{for all }x,y\in \mathbb{Z},\ f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)\}$.

1) For $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ define the function $f_a:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ by the formula  $f_a(x)=ax$. Show that $f_a(x)\in G$

Can you give a hint? I couldn't think anything.

Comment: Can you look my comment below?

Answer (score 0):

Do what they say: check if $f_a(x+y)=f_a(x)+f_a(y)$ holds for all $x,y\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: by the formula, for all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have $f_a(x+y)=a(x+y)=ax+ay$ and by the formula, for all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $f_a(x)+f_a(y)=ax+ay$. Hence, can we say that it holds for all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Kahler Indeed.